# d3 zoom x-domain only

Tags: javascript, d3.js, ember.js

I currently have a d3 bar graph for which I am trying to restrict zooming to only its x-axis.

The data spans a high number of years along the x-axis, resulting in a highly concentrated bar [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iVdW.png). I'd like to be able to zoom along the x-axis, thus spreading the bars farther apart horizontally - similar to what is being done on this line graph [here](https://codepen.io/ghiden/pen/DHCiz).

Right now, I have a function within my ember app in which I select each of the elements within the SVG and zoom in along both axes. How do I restrict zooming to occur only along the x-axis?

enableZoom() {

```
const svg = d3.select('svg');

const zoomHandler = d3.zoom().scaleExtent([1, 2]).on('zoom', zoomed);

const bars = svg.selectAll('.bar'),
      lines = svg.selectAll('.line'),
      circles = svg.selectAll('circle');

zoomHandler(svg);

function zoomed() {

  lines.attr('transform', d3.event.transform);
  circles.attr('transform', d3.event.transform);
  bars.attr('transform', d3.event.transform);

}
```

},

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In v3 it was possible to do:

```
const zoomHandler = d3.behavior.zoom()
  .x(x)
  .scaleExtent([1, 2])
  .on("zoom", zoomed);
```

In v4, we have to rescale our linear scale manually and use the rescaled version to create the axis:

```
function zoomed() {
    const transform = d3.event.transform;

    // rescale the x linear scale so that we can draw the top axis
    const xNewScale = transform.rescaleX(xScale);
    xAxis.scale(xNewScale);
    gAxis.call(xAxis);

    // draw the lines, circles, bars in their new positions
    lines.attr('cx', function(d) { return transform.applyX(xScale(d)); });
    circles.attr('cx', function(d) { return transform.applyX(xScale(d)); });
    bars.attr('cx', function(d) { return transform.applyX(xScale(d)); });
}
```

Checkout [this article](http://emptypipes.org/2016/07/03/d3-panning-and-zooming/) for a good walkthrough.

Comment: Chaining .x(x) doesn't seem to be working.  It's throwing the error "d3..is not a function". This may have been possible in version 3, but not in v4. Any other ideas? Thanks

Comment: Added a v4 solution.